# How to make custom Google fonts fontFamily

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a custom `Text()` to avoid repeating code. I want to know how I can make the Google fonts fontFamily custom so that I can use different fonts for different places.

```
class CText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CText(
      {super.key,
      this.size,
      required this.txt,
      this.color,
      this.fontFamily,
      this.weight});

  final String txt;
  final String? fontFamily;
  final double? size;
  final Color? color;
  final FontWeight? weight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(txt,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size,
          color: color,
          fontWeight: weight,
          fontFamily: fontFamily,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below.
But at first you need to add
this [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) dependency and add the whole style widget in `CText` constructor.

```
Text(
  'This is Google Fonts',
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
),
```

As an example of your code

```
class CText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CText(
      {super.key,
      required this.txt,
      required this.customStyle,
     });

  final String txt;
  final TextStyle? customStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(txt,
        style: GoogleFonts.lato(textStyle: customStyle());
  }
}
```